# make a link if table cell has large data then its height

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I am creating table from code behind to show weekly report. It is working fine. But now problem arises if data is large in table cell. I want to make a link in cell if data is larger to fit in the table cell and onclick show whole data of cell in a popup. or something like this. I try overflow scroll but it looks bad.
My code from which i generating table is:-

```
private void TaskTable(TaskSearch search)
{

    _empList = _objDBL.GetEmpList(ddlCategory.SelectedValue);
    Label heading = new Label();
    heading.Text ="Task Report from "+search.FromDate.ToString("dd MMM,yyyy")+" to "+search.ToDate.ToString("dd MMM,yyyy");
    heading.Attributes.Add("class", "weekheading");

    divTaskTable.Controls.Add(heading);
    Session["Lable"] = heading;
    Table table = new Table();
    TableRow row;
    TableCell cell;
    TableHeaderRow headerRow = new TableHeaderRow();
    TableHeaderCell headerCell;
    table.CssClass = "grid-view";

    headerCell = new TableHeaderCell();
    headerCell.Text = "Emp Name";
    headerRow.Cells.Add(headerCell);
    headerCell = new TableHeaderCell();
    headerCell.Text = "Monday";
    headerRow.Cells.Add(headerCell);
    headerCell = new TableHeaderCell();
    headerCell.Text = "Tuesday";
    headerRow.Cells.Add(headerCell);
    headerCell = new TableHeaderCell();
    headerCell.Text = "Wednesday";
    headerRow.Cells.Add(headerCell);
    headerCell = new TableHeaderCell();
    headerCell.Text = "Thursday";
    headerRow.Cells.Add(headerCell);
    headerCell = new TableHeaderCell();
    headerCell.Text = "Friday";
    headerRow.Cells.Add(headerCell);
    headerCell = new TableHeaderCell();
    headerCell.Text = "Saturday";
    headerRow.Cells.Add(headerCell);

    table.Rows.Add(headerRow);
    for (int i = 0; i < _empList.Count; i++)
    {
        int m=1;
        row = new TableRow();
        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Text = _empList[i].Name;
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
        search.EmpId = _empList[i].Id;
        _taskList = _objDBL.GetSearchedTaskList(search);
        string[] months = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.DayNames;

        for (int j = 0; m < months.Count() && j<_taskList.Count; m++)
        {
            if (_taskList[j].Date.DayOfWeek.ToString().Equals(months[m]))
            {
                cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Text = _taskList[j++].TodaysTask;
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
            }
            else
            {
                cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Text = "-";
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
            }

        }
        for (; m < 7; m++)
        {
            cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Text = "-";
            row.Cells.Add(cell);
        }
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    divTaskTable.Controls.Add(table);
    Session["Table"] = table;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I do it on our site for product descriptions, the text is greater than 75 characters it generates a shorter text then a Full Description link. I'm sure you could modify it to your code. My site is in VB.NET and this code is for a gridview control, but you get the gist of it.

```
 If descLength >= 75 then
      CType(row.FindControl("shortDesc"), Label).Text = CType(row.FindControl("labelDesc"), Label).Text.Substring(0, 74) & "... <a href='/detailsfp.aspx?prodid=" & productIDM & "'>Full Description</a>"
 End If
```

Comment: I need help here,
I have list of texts
each list has 3 column, I am using stringbuilder

foreach (var listitem in audit)
{
sbQuery.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} added {1} as {2}<br/>", listitem.username, listitem.FieldName, listitem.NewValue.Length <= 200 ? listitem.NewValue : "<a  href=''>View</a>"));
                            }
                        }
                    }
I need to show if value is greater than 200 into a new popup